# ScrollView using Button (NGUI C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scrollview, ngui

I'm having a problem implementing the button to swipe it to the next page I am using NGUI

Here's my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NGUI_PageNavigation : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject sv;
public SpringPanel sp = null;
int xSpring = 1278;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    sp = sv.GetComponent<SpringPanel>();
    if (sp == null) sv.AddComponent<SpringPanel>();

}

private void OnStoppedMoving()
{

    int pagewidth = 320;
    int pageposition = (int)sp.target.x;
    int page = System.Math.Abs(pageposition / pagewidth) + 1;

    print("page " + (page));
}


public void LeftArrow()
{

    sp.target.x = 1278;
    sp.target.y = 0;
    sp.target.z = 0;
    sp.target = new Vector3(sp.target.x, sp.target.y, sp.target.z);
    sp.enabled = true;

    //Debug.Log("I've been clicked - Left Arrow()");
}

public void RightArrow()
{
    sp.target.x = -1278;
    sp.target.y = 0;
    sp.target.z = 0;
    sp.target = new Vector3(sp.target.x,sp.target.y,sp.target.z);
    sp.enabled = true;
    //Debug.Log("I've been cliked - Right Arrow()");
}
}
```

it says

> NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required.

Could someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this part of your code:

```
void Start()
{
    sp = sv.GetComponent<SpringPanel>();
    if (sp == null) sv.AddComponent<SpringPanel>();
}
```

If `GetComponent` returns `null` because `SpringPanel` is not attached to the `sv` GameObject, the `SpringPanel` component will be added to the `sv` GameObject. The problem is that `sp` will still be `null`. You should also assign the value returned by `AddComponent` to `sp`.

Replace

```
if (sp == null) 
    sv.AddComponent<SpringPanel>();
```

with

```
if (sp == null) 
    sp = sv.AddComponent<SpringPanel>();
```

Comment: Thank you . That was so dumb of me . I'm very sorry

Comment: Not dumb. We all learn! No problem. You can accept when you can